# ATI Stream compared to NVidia/CUDA

Tags: gpgpu

In an effort to make this an answerable question, and not just an opinion poll, I'll ask it like this:

Are there any third-party reports that compare ATI's Stream framework to NVidia's CUDA framework (ie, not from ATI or NVidia talking themselves up)?

Answer (score 2):

Tom's Hardware has an article, [ATI Stream: Finally, CUDA Has Competition](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/amd-stream-gpgpu,2335.html) (2009-06-15).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of such a comparison, but I'll add some personal experience to the mix. Maybe between the users here we can develop a decent comparison/pros/cons/experience/lessons.

NVIDIA:

1. Linux support (just use the binary blob and deal with it)
2. Compiler support, GCC 4.1 and 4.2. 4.3 still has issues.

Answer (score 0):

Such a direct comparison would require someone to build a computational test suite which is API independent and runs on both CUDA and ATi Stream. People have tried but no platform independent solution is out yet. May be one of the GPU benchmarking powerhouses can get this done. There are other projects such as MAGMA or GPUlib which are blossoming under Nvidia tutelage. The world of GPGPU is very partisan indeed.

Answer (score 0):

From a software perspective, it is not an apples-apples comparison since the programming models of the two are very different,

An application may map efficiently to Brook+ and not to CUDA or vice-versa. Optimum usage of hardware by writing good code makes a big difference

Answer (score 0):

LAMMPS is one of the most successful GPU-based molecular dynamic simulators. Axel Kohlmeyer, the main developer, has reported their experimental results [on this page in the attachment of the post](http://lammps.sandia.gov/threads/msg24562.html). These results are fair and useful.